# Security for deployed application in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

I have created a REST service and deployed over cloud using GAE. I don't want it to be accessed by any one just by using the URL. I should have some control over there to provide the authentication, may be along with the request.

I explored and got some OAuth related tutorials, but could not understand properly.

Please help me regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably consider using OAuth 2.0, as in near future you might need further authorization. Further you can implement your own basic authentication (not recommended though) by something like this:

Provide users with URL, ID and a Secret.
Ask them to create a signature using 'Secret' and Random number with some hashing (SHA/md5).
They should then, along with request url, send Random number, ID and signature.
On your end, you also calculate signature for the given ID with given supplied Random number.
If the signature matches, request is authentic.

Why I said not recommended is, you can use some existing OAuth mechanism. You should consider reading this as well: [Securing my REST API with OAuth while still allowing authentication via third party OAuth providers (using DotNetOpenAuth)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574868/securing-my-rest-api-with-oauth-while-still-allowing-authentication-via-third-pa)

Comment: Thanks @Rajat, OAuth is being used if third party accessing the application(if i m correct). But in my case, I just want to make the service private to my client or u can say that shd not be accessible to everyone. please suggest.

Comment: I think the method I suggested will work fine for you then. I have used the same sometime back.  ""Provide users with URL, ID and a Secret. Ask them to create a signature using 'Secret' and Random number with some hashing (SHA/md5). They should then, along with request url, send Random number, ID and signature. On your end, you also calculate signature for the given ID with given supplied Random number. If the signature matches, request is authentic.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking with a really easy way and you're willing to accept limitations, like having to use a browser as a client and using Google accounts, try the User API.