# OAuth2 for custom API

Tags: php, api, rest, oauth-2.0, laravel-4

I'm trying to use OAuth2 for an API I'm creating but could use some explanation for how the flow would work. I've found similar questions (ex: [Securing my REST API with OAuth while still allowing authentication via third party OAuth providers (using DotNetOpenAuth)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4574868/1035497)) but they don't make things clear with regards to the third-party login.

I do not wish to use OpenID (yet, anyways), especially when authentication by delegation might work just fine. It seems overly complicated and does not have many well-supported libraries. (I'm using PHP + Laravel 4)

The problem is separated into 4(ish) entities:

- Resource Owner - The end user
- Client - Browser (My website), a mobile app, or similar
- Authorization Server - My OAuth2 server
- Resource Server - My API. Serves user data.

I think I've figured out the flow for when the user creates an account at my auth server and uses that account to log in:

1. User fills in username/password on Client.
2. Client connects to Auth Server using the Resource Owner flow, authenticates the User, and authorizes the Client automatically.
3. The user is redirected from the AUth Server back to the Client, with a Token + signed JWT containing a user ID.
4. Client saves the token in a session.
5. Client uses the token + signed JWT user id to request data from the Resource Server.
6. The Resource Server validates the JWT and returns data depending on the token scopes.

I haven't tested the workflow yet, but this seems like it would work. Third-party login, however, has proven to be more difficult. This is what I've got so far:

1. User clicks login with Google/Facebook/LinkedIn.
2. User is redirected from Client to Google's Auth Server (not mine).
3. User logs in using user/pass and authorizes Client to fetch some protected resource (userinfo.email) - This authenticates the user by delegation.
4. User is redirected back to Client, with a Token + signed JWT containing a Google user id.
5. Client validates the JWT.
6. Client uses the Client Credentials flow to connect to the Resource Server. Recieves a new token.
7. Client saves the token in a session.
8. Client requests to convert the Google user id to an application user id. (This connection was made during signup.)
9. Resource Server returns the application user id. (Signed JWT)
10. Client uses the token + signed JWT user id to request data from the Resource Server.
11. The Resource Server validates the JWT and returns data depending on the token scopes.

This might work, but it feels awfully complicated. Surely there must be a way to skip a few of those steps? I'm particularly interested in step 8-10. As far as I know, the user never have to interact with my Auth Server at all using third-party login. The problem is how you best connect a successful id_token (or something) from Google/Facebook/LinkedIn to the "account" resource at my API.

Right now, I'm not worried about any other clients connecting to the API, but it's something that will happen sometime in the future.

Comment: I don't think any of these APIs provide the user's email. So you may not have a unique id to group multiple social account log ins. What you can do is ask the user to enter their details after been authenticated from the API.

For your side of the API i suggest using an OAuth2 API framework. They have everything build inside which will leave you more time to worry about other things. :)

Answer (score 0):

*"As far as I know, the user never have to interact with my Auth Server at all using third-party login."*
That's only partly true. Theoretically, you could use the token of the Third-Party login as your own. So a normal resource request would be:

1. Client requests resource - sends token (from 3rd party) and type of login (facebook/google/etc)
2. Server validates request by checking the token with the 3rd party Authorization Server and returns data.

The downside with that is, that your API server has to talk with the 3rd party server every time a request gets made (whether data from them is needed or not). Instead when you generate your own token you have more control and it's simpler to validate requests.

I would stick with your workflow though. I did something similar once and my steps were pretty much the same. When "counting" steps you also have to consider, that for step 2-4 you basically have to do nothing since the Google, Facebook and co have done a good job already ;)

Answer (score 0):

A late contribution to your question.

Found this resource explaining the use of OAuth2 : [OAuth2 in 8 Steps](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/oauth)